# What exactly is the difference between 哲 and 喆？

Tags: difference, characters, topolect

I'm also interested in knowing the connotations and whether those terms are associated with specific dialects. Would the average mainland speaker know 喆?

Comment: https://cantoneseplus.com/character/4940 . 喆 is a variant of 哲, you can presume there is no difference in meaning. I personally have never written the character 喆 in my life

Comment: As native speaker my feeling is that is standard Chinese 喆 is exclusive to person names. Can't think of a single context that uses 喆 outside names.

Comment: Another example is 淼, which is a variant of 渺, but only used in person names.

Comment: Could a person theoretically be named 永水淼 for example？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The average speaker will likely recognize 喆 as it is used in person names, but will not recognize it as a variant of 哲.